# optimize merging two lists of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

i have two lists, each one contains 10-15k dictionaries.
the first list named `campaigns` and it contains dictionaries with the following structure:

```
{u'campaign_id': u'400037', u'ctr': u'1.1210', u'roi': 0, u'end_date': None, u'revenue': 0.0, u'website_id': 1, u'enabled': u'active', u'budget': u'100.00', u'default_bid': u'0.05', u'cost': 30.63, u'start_date': u'2018-02-13'}
```

and the second list - `yesterday_data`  dict's structure is:

```
{u'cost': 0.0, u'campaign_id': u'400037', u'revenue': 0.0}
```

goal is to match campaign id's, and add two key's to the relevant dict in `campaigns_data` where `yesterday_date["revenue"]` and `yesterday_date["cost"]` will be a new keys in `campaigns_data` dict - `yesterday_cost` and `yesterday_revenue`

i managed to a achieve this logic with the following code:

```
campaigns = model.get_campaigns_data(self.mysql_db)
yesterday_data = model.get_yesterday_data(self.mysql_db, yesterday)
try:
    for campaign in campaigns:
        missing = filter(lambda c: c["campaign_id"] == str(campaign["campaign_id"]), yesterday_data)
        if not missing:
            pass
        else:
            campaign["yesterday_spend"] = missing[0]["cost"]
            campaign["yesterday_revenue"] = missing[0]["revenue"]
```

but with this numbers of dictionaries inside each list it's extremely slow and ,i want to believe, far fro being the optimized way to achieve that.
any idea how can i improve my code to get the same result?

Comment: Invert the dictionary. Make it so `campaign_id` becomes the key and maps to the reference to the corresponding dictionary for each dataset, then you can loop over one of those and do it in O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `id` and reduce:

```
grouper = {}
for d in campaigns_data:
    grouper[d["campaign_id"]] = d

# assuming the keys match up:

for d in yesterday_data:
    grouper[["campaign_id"]].update(yesterday_spend=d['cost'],
                                    yesterday_revenue=d['revenue'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> d1 = {u'campaign_id': u'400037', u'ctr': u'1.1210', u'roi': 0, u'end_date': None, u'revenue': 0.0, u'website_id': 1, u'enabled': u'active', u'budget': u'100.00', u'default_bid': u'0.05', u'cost': 30.63, u'start_date': u'2018-02-13'}
>>> d2 = {u'cost': 0.0, u'campaign_id': u'400037', u'revenue': 0.0}

>>> if d1["campaign_id"] == d2["campaign_id"]:
      d1.update(d2)
```

Output

```
{u'roi': 0, u'ctr': u'1.1210', u'end_date': None, u'revenue': 0.0, u'website_id': 1, u'enabled': u'active', u'campaign_id': u'400037', u'budget': u'100.00', u'default_bid': u'0.05', u'cost': 0.0, u'start_date': u'2018-02-13'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to do this. Convert both these dictionaries to pandas dataframe and then merge them.

*Note:* I am doing this for one row. If you have 100 rows replace the `index=[0]` to `index = range(100)` in the lines where I am constructing `df_1` and `df_2`

```
campaigns = {u'campaign_id': u'400037', u'ctr': u'1.1210', u'roi': 0, u'end_date': None, u'revenue': 0.0, u'website_id': 1, u'enabled': u'active', u'budget': u'100.00', u'default_bid': u'0.05', u'cost': 30.63, u'start_date': u'2018-02-13'}

yesterday_data = {u'cost': 0.0, u'campaign_id': u'400037', u'revenue': 0.0}

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(campaigns, index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(yesterday_data, index=[0])

df_new = df1.merge(df2, on=['campaign_id'])
```

to get back the dictionary form, do:

```
df_new.to_dict(orient='records')
```

*Note 2*:
The keys from `yesterday_data` for example, for example `cost` and `revenue` will end with `_y` as suffix and for keys from `campaigns` will have keys with suffix `_x`. This is for the keys which are common between the two dataframes.